# How to solve Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid address error with web3 js

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, metamask, ganache

Whenever I run the code I get an error saying

> "Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid address (argument="address", value=["0xF628D397c2C1c4cB485BDF5441ac723B229f4F8f"], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.0.2) (argument=null, value=["0xF628D397c2C1c4cB485BDF5441ac723B229f4F8f"], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.0-beta.153)".

I don't know why this problem occurs since I am able to return the account value. I have no idea what is the problem with my account. Here is my code,

```
 import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react';
 import './App.css';
 import Navbar from './Navbar';
 import Web3 from 'web3';
 import Tether from '../truffle_abis/Tether.json';

 const App = () => {

useEffect(() => {
    loadWeb3();

    updateBlockchainData();
    loadBlockchainData();
}, [])

const loadWeb3 = async()=>{
    if(window.ethereum){
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        await window.ethereum.enable();
    }else if(window.web3){
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
    }else{
        window.alert("No ethereum browser detected! You can check out MetaMask!");
    }
}

const loadBlockchainData=async()=>{
    const web3 = window.web3;
    const account = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    setAccount(account[0]);
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const tetherData = Tether.networks[networkId];
    if(tetherData){
        const tether = new web3.eth.Contract(Tether.abi,tetherData.address);
        setTether(tether);
        console.log(account);
        let tetherBalance = await tether.methods.balanceOf(account).call();
       setTetherBalance(tetherBalance.toString());
         console.log(tetherBalance);
    }else{
        window.alert("Error! Tether Contract not deployed - No network detected!");
    }
    console.log(networkId);
    console.log(account);
}

const updateBlockchainData = async()=>{
    const web3 = window.web3;
           window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged",async function(){
        let account = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
         console.log(account);
    })
}

const [account,setAccount] = useState("0x0454656");
const [tether,setTether] = useState({});
const [rwd,setRwd] = useState({});
const [decentralBank,setDecentralBank] = useState({});
const [tetherBalance,setTetherBalance] = useState("0");
const [rwdBalance,setRwdBalance] = useState("0");
const [stakingBalance,setStakingBalance] = useState("0");
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true); 


return (
    <div>
        <Navbar account={account} />
    </div>
)

}

export default App
```

The problem is with my "tetherBalance" variable which has the methods.balanceOf().call() function.Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says *invalid address* and display

```
value=["0xF628D397c2C1c4cB485BDF5441ac723B229f4F8f"],
```

So the code is using an array as address. The problem is in the initialization, `web3.eth.getAccounts()` returns an array and you only want the first position. Something like this should work:

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
const account = accounts[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Tbh, I don't why it's happening but I found a solution. The problem is using state.

At this line, don't use **account**

```
let tetherBalance = await tether.methods.balanceOf(account).call();
```

Your code should be like this;

```
      const web3 = window.web3;
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
       
      // declare a new object **localAccount** and set account to it
      const localAccount = accounts[0];
      setAccount(accounts[0]);
      const netWorkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();

      // Load Tether Contract
      const tetherData = Tether.networks[netWorkId];
      if (tetherData) {
        const tether = new web3.eth.Contract(Tether.abi, tetherData.address);
        setTether(tether);

        // At this line use **localAccount**
        let tetherBalance = await tether.methods.balanceOf(localAccount).call();
        setTetherBalance(tetherBalance.toString());
      } else {
        window.alert(
          "Error! Tether contract not deployed - no detected network!"
        );
      }
```

Comment: Explanation of @0xazat answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/129716/102477 : State Updates May Be Asynchronous
Often times you run into an issue like this ```const handleEvent = e => { setState(e.target.value); console.log(state); }``` where the state is not the most up-to-date value when you log it. This is caused by state updates being asynchronous. So the account state hasn't been updated before `tether.methods.balanceOf()` carries out it's function hence the error

Comment: @NooblantisDistrict I moved the answer to a comment. Unfortunately code formatting doesn't work in comments.